# Create a React component lib

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I'm trying to create a library with reusable react components. I'm using React, Typescript, Sass and Webpack.

My problem is : when I'm using my components from the result of the webpack build, there is no css with them although I have an index.css file with everything I need.
It seems like the css is not used by the output.

Here is my webpack.config.json :

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.ts'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'whatever',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.build.json')
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              camelCase: true,
              sourceMap: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules", "src"],
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.scss', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'index.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css',
    }),
  ]
};
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT 1:** 
As suggested by **Muhammad Mehar** I changed the `loader: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, ...` to `use: [...` but it didn't work

Here is how I'm trying to use my lib :
*somewhereInTargetApp.ts*

```
import { MyComponent } from 'MyLib';

export const OtherComponent = (props) => {
   return (
       <MyComponent someProp={'Hello world'}/>
   )
};
```

And in my lib I have some `index.ts` file which exports the component.
Everything works fine for the component except that there is no css with it

Comment: Can you provide an example of how are you trying to use the result?

Answer (score 0):

**Rule.loader** is a shortcut to Rule.use: [ { loader } ].

Passing a string (i.e. loader: 'style-loader' ) is a shortcut to the loader property (i.e. use: [ { loader: 'style-loader '} ])

**Rule.use** can be an array of UseEntry which are applied to modules. Each entry specifies a loader to be used.

Passing a string (i.e. use: [ 'style-loader' ]) is a shortcut to the loader property (i.e. use: [ { loader: 'style-loader '} ])

Loaders can be chained by passing multiple loaders, which will be applied from right to left (last to first configured)

Try this:

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.tsx?/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: {
      configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.build.json')
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          camelCase: true,
          sourceMap: false
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
]},
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I changed it but sadly it didn't work.  
I knew I had to use 'use', I do not know how I missed it

Answer (score 0):

In the end I switched to CSS in JS with [aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite)
This is not what I wanted to do but it will do the work for now

If someone has an answer to my problem I would be happy to test it